# Double integral giving different results after changing order of integration

Tags: multiple-integral

A double integral defined by $$\iint\frac xy dA$$ is integrated over the region of $1<x<3, x<y<2x$. Using different orders of integration produces different results as demonstrated below:
$$\begin{align*}
 \int_1^3\int_x^{2x}\frac xy \ dy \ dx&=\int_1^3[x\ln y]_x^{2x} dx\\ &=\int_1^3x\ln2x - x\ln x\,dx\\
&=\int_1^3x\ln\frac{2x}x\,dx\\
&=\int_1^3x\ln2\,dx\\
&=\ln2\left[\frac {x^2}2\right]_1^3\\
&=\ln2\cdot\frac{3^2-1^2}2\\
&=4\ln2.
\end{align*}$$

On the other hand,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_1^6\int_\frac y2^{y}\frac xy \ dx \ dy
&=\int_1^6\left[\frac {x^2}{2y}\right]_{\frac y2}^{y} \ dy\\
&=\int_1^6 \frac y2 - \frac y8 \ dy\\
&=\left(\frac 12 - \frac 18\right)\left[\frac {y^2}2\right]_1^6\\
&=\left(\frac 12 - \frac 18\right)\left(\frac {6^2}2-\frac {1^2}2\right)\\
& =\frac{105}{16}.
\end{align*}$$

What is the mistake here? Is this integral somehow divergent over its domain? Or have I interpreted the bounds incorrectly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The bounds of integration are off. Draw the picture of the region that you're integrating over. You'll find that switching the order of integration will result in three different double integrals to evaluate due to the awkward nature of the boundary.

Comment: It can't be divergent since it is bounded and $A$ is relatively compact, the rest is explained by josh

Comment: The mistake is here: "$\int_1^6\int_\frac y2^{y}\frac xy \ dx \ dy$". The bounds for $x$ are $y/2,y$ only when $2\le y\le3,$ as shown by GEdgar's picture.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As Josh and GEdgar pointed out, you should calculate the following three double integrals and sum them.

$\begin{align}\displaystyle\int_1^2\!\mathrm dy\!\int_1^y\frac xy\,\mathrm dx&=\int_1^2\left[\frac{x^2}{2y}\right]_1^y\mathrm dy=\!\int_1^2\left(\frac y2-\frac1{2y}\right)\mathrm dy=\\[3pt]&=\left[\frac{y^2}4-\frac12\ln y\right]_1^2=\frac34-\frac12\ln2\end{align}$

$\displaystyle\int_2^3\mathrm dy\int_{\frac y2}^y\frac xy\,\mathrm dx=\int_2^3\left[\frac{x^2}{2y}\right]_{\frac y2}^y\mathrm dy=\int_2^3\left(\frac y2-\frac y8\right)\mathrm dy=\frac{15}{16}$

$\begin{align}\displaystyle\int_3^6\mathrm dy\int_{\frac y2}^3\frac xy\,\mathrm dx&=\int_3^6\left[\frac{x^2}{2y}\right]_{\frac y2}^3\mathrm dy=\int_3^6\left(\frac9{2y}-\frac y8\right)\mathrm dy=\\[3pt]&=\left[\frac92\ln y-\frac{y^2}{16}\right]_3^6=\frac92\ln2-\frac{27}{16}\end{align}$

If you sum the results of the previous three double integrals, you get $\,4\ln2\,$ which is what you obtained by using the other order of integration.

Comment: Why have you downvoted my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Hint...  $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$
[image: A]